Windows Server - RDP into a Domain Controller gives error "No License Server was Available"
When logging on to a Windows Server via Remote Desktop (RDP), I receive the message "No License Server was Available".


I’m voting to close this question because Domain Controllers should not have Remote Desktop Service installed

The quick and dirty to bypass this if you have access via a HyperVisor console was to run the following 2 commands in a PowerShell or CMD window on the Domain Controller. This allows the normal 2 concurrent user RDP sessions to the Server.
dism /ONLINE /Disable-feature /FeatureName:Remote-Desktop-Services
dism /ONLINE /Disable-feature /FeatureName:Licensing

If you do not have access to any Admin Session you can get access via a local computer with the following commands
mstsc /v:<Server>[:<Port>] /admin

The solution is documented in Depth in the Microsoft Article
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/virtual-machines/windows/troubleshoot-rdp-no-license-server
